# possible to stream audio from Ipod via Bluetooth to Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, ipod, stream

Hi I am wondering if it is at all possible to stream audio from Ipod via Bluetooth to Ubuntu ?

I cant seem to get my Ipod Touch6 recognized in Ubuntu (Bluetooth is picking up other devices in the area, just not my Ipod, which has Bluetooth turned on)

Running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Comment: Is visiblity(discoverable mode) enabled on the Ipod?

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible.

Check if the necessary packages are installed:

```
dpkg -l bluez pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python-gobject python-gobject-2
```

if not, install them.

Edit your `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` and uncomment or add

```
[A2DP]
Enable=Source,Sink,Media,Socket
SCORouting=PCM
AutoConnect=true
```

The above is enough to make a Samsung Galaxy S5 connect.

If this isn't enough to recognize the iPod, change your class of device (COD) in `main.conf`. The audio device class (commented out) is `#Class = 0x000100`. This is in 16.04, maybe your value is different. If you uncomment this, the iPod should connect.

Reference for [device classes from Bluetooth SIG](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/baseband).

You basically need to make sure that your computer advertises itself as an audio device, so the iPod is willing to pair with it.

Comment: I attempted to  do everything you said . The first part above  had no effect , and second  part of the solution `Class = 0x000100`  was already   uncommented.

Comment: Has the iPod connected to other Bluetooth audio devices successfully?

Comment: other devises yes, but havent tried with audio devices.

Comment: Try *commenting out* the `Class = 0x000100` line for a change. Don't forget to reload the Bluetooth module afterwards.

Comment: this had no effect. The Ipod is still undetected.

Comment: I expanded the answer to cover more. Please try.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The output of `sudo dpkg -l bluez pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python-gobject python-gobject-2` can be seen at https://paste.ubuntu.com/16231393/

Comment: Your output shows all is installed. Can you initiate pairing from the computer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39319/discussion-between-kalamalka-kid-and-emk2203).